# Implementing PAM authentication

Tags: python, pam, fingerprint-reader

How can I write a script in Python, that is going to be invoked by applications requesting PAM authentication? I imagine fingerprint readers have the same problem.

What are the packages or frameworks that can be used?

Related to [Login Screen source code](https://askubuntu.com/questions/864508/login-screen-source-code)